# Preventing double click on onclick in Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I use `onclick` to fire my function but I want to prevent the function to be called when double click action is made.

How can I achieve it on Svelte? Does Svelte have any special way of registering only one click but not double?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement this behavior by e.g. setting a boolean to `true` when the click handler is called, and use a timeout to reset it back to `false` after some period of time. If this boolean is `true` on a new click you ignore it.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/175a1a8eecaa46c6bfeaa81b8bafedd2?version=3.32.3))**

```html
<script>
    let hasBeenClicked = false;
    
    function handleClick() {
        if (hasBeenClicked) return;
        
        hasBeenClicked = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            hasBeenClicked = false;
        }, 200);
        
        console.log('click');
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing build in into Svelte to do this.

But this can be easily done by wrapping the function you want to execute in a throttle function, which will basically limit the number of clicks one can make within a specific time frame.

There are a lot of snippets for throttle functions to be found online, or you can use one of the myriad npm packages that do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

there is now an event modifier "once" that achieves this.
https://svelte.dev/tutorial/event-modifiers

```
<script>
    function handleClick() {
        console.log('click');
    }
</script>

<button on:click|once={handleClick}>Click me</button>
```

Comment: The question is about disabling double-click actions. The once modifier completely disables the event after one click. The accepted answer clearly indicates single-click actions are still desired.